# org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible vmcid: IBM minor code: E07 from IIB application

Tags: java, websphere, corba, ibm-integration-bus, iiop

I am working on IIB 10.There is a soap application in which an iiop URL is called using java compute node.I am getting the following error"org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No"

Answer (score 0):

It means the IIOP url cannot be reached, or is refusing to communicate for some other reason.

Comment: The iiop url is having port 2811.ESB server is having connection to the bootstrap port(2811) and orb listener port(9102) in that remote server.